# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception when using GWT + JasperReports

Tags: gwt, jasper-reports

I have integrated `JasperReports` on my `NetBeans` platform and I am able to generate reports using the following code:

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("databaseUrl", "userid", "password");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, conn);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, reportDest);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
```

This stuff works perfect.

But not I'm trying to integrate `JasperReports` with `GWT`. I have my server as `GlassFish` server.

I am getting the Connection object using the followind code:

```java
public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        String JNDI = "JNDI name";
        InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
        javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) initCtx.lookup(JNDI);
        Connection conn = (Connection) ds.getConnection();
        return conn;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, getConnection());
JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, reportDest);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
```

but i always get an Error.  Here is a stacktrace:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: 
Service method 'public abstract java.lang.Boolean com.client.service.GenerateReport()'
threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily.setExportFonts(Ljava/util/Map‌​);
```

I am implementing this on Server. I am having RPC calls to get this method to work when a button is clicked.

Can you please help me how to work on this. (That is to integrate `JasperReports` with `GWT`).

I would highly appreciate any explanation with some code as i am just a beginner.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, a better error classification would definitely help.

Comment: The error which i am getting is 
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.Boolean com.client.service.GenerateReport()' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily.setExportFonts(Ljava/util/Map);

Comment: Did you get your answer. I am on the same issue? Thank You

Comment: I think that problem is that the client and server sides are using the different version of `JasperReports` library.

The first step to resolving this problem is to use the same version of JR library.

Answer (score -1):

Without the aid of error messages, I would say that you have Google App Engine enabled in your eclipse project preferences. GAE **does NOT** allow you to write to the file system, or make calls to a database.

Try disabling GAE, and things should work fine.

Comment: @Maksim - He does not *intentionally* use GAE. The GWT eclipse plugin *by default* has GAE enabled. Many, many people have it enabled by default, and realize it only when they encounter an exception not too different from the one pasted above.

Comment: How do we disable GAE in Netbeans?

Comment: Netbeans doesn't have a GWT plugin, so unless you have downloaded GAE and have included the jars, I don't think GAE is the problem. Since you are getting NoSuchMethodError, its possible you have conflicting jars in your classpath. I am guessing two jars have different versions of `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily`.

Comment: I cleaned up my library and made sure that i have only one copy of jar files in my library.But still i get the same error which i copy pasted before.Is there some thing which i am missing still?